# Redirect to different part of application in Blazor if user is not authenticated

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to define a Blazor website that has complete navigation to present the application for non-authenticated users and another completely different navigation for authenticated users.

The idea is that non-authenticated users get to a part of the website that allows anonymous users, with a complete set of pages and navigation. Once they log in, they get to another part of the website which is only for authenticated users with its own navigation.

In addition, I might have two different sets of navigation based on the roles of the users.

For example, an admin might have other views and menus than a standard user.

I have looked at the Routing and navigation documentation, but can't find anything that would allow me to redirect the user based on its authentication state or role to another sub-route with its own MainLayout, etc.

Comment: Could you please look to the answer, I am not sure if that what you meant!

Answer (score 1):

- App.razor:

  ```
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
      <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
     </Router>
  </CascadingAuthenticationState>
  ```
- NavMenu.razor

  ```
  <AuthorizeView>
     <Authorized>
        @* For authorized users *@
        <nav>...</nav>
     </Authorized>
     <NotAuthorized>
        @* For unauthorized users *@
        <nav>...</nav>
     </NotAuthorized>
  </AuthorizeView>
  ```
- Don't forget to add in Startup or program file this two lines.

  ```
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  ```

[Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I had seen this approach, but it means that I need to have this `<AuthorizeView>` in the `NavMenu` and in the `Index` and basically "switch" my views based on which user role I have. 

I hoped to be able to have a completely different layout, and also maybe a different navigation route. A bit like having two different applications in one, one for non-authenticated and one for authenticated.

Comment: I think you can find what you need here plus the solution app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager Navigator { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Navigator.NavigateTo("/SecretPage");
        }
        else
        {
            Navigator.NavigateTo("/PublicPage");
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add this to your startup file:
`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
That will make sure IHttpContextAccessor can be injected.

NaviationManager does not need to be manually injected.

Comment: thanks for your answer. You can not use `HttpContextAccessor` in the server side for security and if does work in development mode but you will get an error in the production. You don't have to use `navigate` in this case, it is better to use `@attribute [Authorize]` in the up of the page.

Comment: I did not know you couldn't use HttpContextAccessor in production when using server sided blazor. Thanks for telling me... I think I just got a lot more work to do :)

Comment: Even if you could use `HttpContextAccessor` nothing would stop a non authenticated user from manually navigating to `/SecretPage`. That is why other answers and comments point to `[Authorize]`